# How do I mock this client in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to mock this flag client properly in Java but I'm not sure how to do it. Normally, I would mock third party apis via WireMock (mock the call) and it will help me mock it and add a test for it. However, the actual call and logic is masked under this client object, I'm not sure if I'm mocking it properly.

Here's some code from the docs: https://docs.flagsmith.com/clients/server-side#initialise-the-sdk

I have this setup right now in my codebase however:

Implementation:

```
@Gateway
public class FlagsmithGateway implements FlagsmithPort {

    private final FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient;

    @Autowired
    public FlagsmithGateway(@Value("${flagsmith.environment.id}") String flagsmithEnvironmentId,
                            @Value("${flagsmith.endpoint}") String flagsmithEndpoint) {

        this(FlagsmithClient
            .newBuilder()
            .setApiKey(flagsmithEnvironmentId)
            .withApiUrl(flagsmithEndpoint)
            .build());
    }

    public FlagsmithGateway(FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient) {
        this.flagsmithClient = flagsmithClient;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(FeatureFlags flag) throws FlagsmithClientError {
        Flags flags = flagsmithClient.getEnvironmentFlags();
        return flags.isFeatureEnabled(flag.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDisabled(FeatureFlags flag) throws FlagsmithClientError {
        Flags flags = flagsmithClient.getEnvironmentFlags();
        return !flags.isFeatureEnabled(flag.toString());
    }
```

}

Test class for implementation above:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FlagsmithGatewayTest  {
    
    private FlagsmithGateway flagsmithGateway;

    @Mock
    private FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        flagsmithGateway = new FlagsmithGateway(flagsmithClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void isEnabled_shouldReturnWhetherFeatureIsEnabled() throws FlagsmithClientError {
        flagsmithClient = mock(FlagsmithClient.class);
        Flags flags = setupFlags("test_toggle", true);

        when(flagsmithClient.getEnvironmentFlags()).thenReturn(flags);=

        boolean result = flagsmithGateway.isEnabled(FeatureFlags.TOGGLE_FOR_TESTS); 

        assertThat(result).isTrue();
    }

    private static Flags setupFlags(String featureName, Boolean enabled) {
        Flags flag = new Flags();
        BaseFlag baseFlag = new BaseFlag();
        Map<String, BaseFlag> someFlags = new HashMap<>();

        baseFlag.setFeatureName(featureName);
        baseFlag.setEnabled(enabled);
        someFlags.put(featureName,baseFlag);
        flag.setFlags(someFlags);

        return flag;
    }
}
```

EDIT: The code above almost works but on this line after calling `flagsmithGateway.isEnabled(FeatureFlags.TOGGLE_FOR_TESTS)` in the tests, I get this an NPE on this line. Flags is null

```
flags.isFeatureEnabled(flag.toString());
```

Any reason why? I'm using Junit 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test `FlagsmithGateway` , you only need to verify if its methods interact correctly with its dependency (i.e. `FlagsmithClient`) such as if it really calls the expected method with the expected parameters .In this case, you just simply need to mock `FlagsmithClient` and stub its `getEnvironmentFlags()`.

In order to allow `FlagsmithGateway` able to use the mocked `FlagsmithClient` , you need to have some way to pass the `FlagsmithClient` into it. (e.g via constructor or setter). So firstly , I would refactor your  gateway a little bit such that it allows to create with `FlagsmithClient` through constructor directly.

```java
@Gateway
public class FlagsmithGateway implements FlagsmithPort {

    private final FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient; 

    @Autowired
    public FlagsmithGateway(@Value("${flagsmith.apikey}") String flagsmithApiKey,
                            @Value("${flagsmith.endpoint}") String flagsmithEndpoint) {
        this(FlagsmithClient
            .newBuilder()
            .setApiKey(flagsmithApiKey)
            .withApiUrl(flagsmithEndpoint)
            .build());
    }

    public FlagsmithGateway(FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient) {
        this.flagsmithClient = flagsmithClient;
    }

}
```

And the test would use this constructor to create `FlagsmithGateway` :

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FlagsmithGatewayTest extends GatewayIntegrationTest {

    FlagsmithGateway flagsmithGateway;

    @Mock
    FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        flagsmithGateway = new FlagsmithGateway(flagsmithClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void isEnabled_shouldReturnWhetherFeatureIsEnabled() throws FlagsmithClientError {

        Flags flags = defaultFlagHandler("test_toggle", true);
        when(client.getEnvironmentFlags()).thenReturn(flags);
        
        FeatureFlags featureFlags = xxxxx //create it based on your logic

        boolean result = flagsmithGateway.isEnabled(featureFlags);
        assertThat(result).isTrue();
    }

}
```

Please note that I am using the plain Mockito test to manually create a `FlagsmithGateway` but not using spring-boot-test mainly because the way that you setup in spring will make it to use the constructor

```java
new FlagsmithGateway(String flagsmithApiKey,String flagsmithEndpoint)
```

to create a `FlagsmithGateway` but it always hardcode to use the real `FlagsmithClient` instance.

If you really want to verify the codes in your original constructor works as expected , you can create another test for it :

```java
@Test
public void flagsmithClientCreatedProperly(){
   FlagsmithGateway gateway = new FlagsmithGateway("apiKey" , "http://foo");

  //get the FlagsmithClient from  FlagsmithGateway and the assert tis apiKey and apiUrl 
}
```

Comment: FlagsmithClient is still null. What could I be doing wrong above?

Comment: @Euridice01 Doesn't look like the mock is being initialised. Try `FlagsmithClient flagsmithClient = Mockito.mock(FlagsmithClient .class);`. And... are you using Spring in your tests? Why adding so much complexity to something simple?

Comment: I added that line but when it goes to this line, it fails: flags.isFeatureEnabled(flag.toString()); because Flags isn't properly mocked. 

I'm happy to start the test from scratch and understand how to properly set this up. Having a lot of difficulty.

Comment: @Euridice01 , how do you create `FlagsmithGateway` in your test ? I am suggesting to create it using a new constructor with explicitly pass the mocked `FlagsmithClient` into it. I just updated my answers to mentioned it more clearly. please check.

Comment: Forget to mention in my original answer , in order to make `@Mock` to take effect , you have to make sure `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` is annotated on your test class

Comment: Hi all, I just updated my post with the latest changes. It's still failing because the `FlagsmithGateway` is null. Can you please review? I think we're getting close but still running into a few issues. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: You are using junit4 or junit5 actually? just noticed that you are actually using junit4 from the codes that you edit before ?

Comment: Sorry, we have both junit4 and junit 5 tests in our code. Since this will be new code, let's stick to junit 5. I double checked some of the imports and now the gateway is not null anymore but on the line above. I edited my post with some new details. Thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248998/discussion-between-euridice01-and-ken-chan).

Comment: Hey, I'm an idiot. I removed the .mock(FlagsmithClient.class) above and now it's only using the @Mock and it's working now. My bad and thanks again for all your help! Really appreciate it! It was probably related to that and the junit 4/5 differences that made me pull hairs lol.